# Retrieving ID of newly provisioned EC2 instance

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I am trying to speed up the time it takes me to launch instances from a specific AMI using [this](http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/php/post/TxMLFLE50WUAMR/-Provision-an-Amazon-EC2-span-class-matches-Instance-span-with-PHP) AWS blog post as a starting point, however I am not sure how to grab the ID of the newly acquired Instance I have spun up using V3 of the PHP API (opposed to V2 in the blog post) so I can retrieve further information about the Instance (using the ID I would have retrieved)

```
<?php

require 'C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\vendor\autoload.php';

use Aws\Ec2\Ec2Client;

$ec2Client = \Aws\Ec2\Ec2Client::factory(array(
    'region'  => 'eu-west-1',
    'version' => 'latest'
));

//Default vars
$aws_key = 'aws-ireland';
$ami_id = 'ami-000000';
$min_count = '1';
$max_count = '1';
$instance_type = 't2.micro';
$instance_region = 'eu-west-1b';
$server_name = 'API Test Server';

$result = $ec2Client->runInstances(array (
    //Creating the instance
    'KeyName' => $aws_key,
    'ImageId' => $ami_id,
    'MinCount' => $min_count,
    'MaxCount' => $max_count,
    'InstanceType' => $instance_type,
    'Placement' => array('AvailabilityZone' => $instance_region),
));

//Wait for server to be created

//Return the instance ID
```

Following the blog post any further from this results in errors as the method waitUntilInstanceRunning doesn't exist in V3 of the API. I believe I need to use a waiter, but I'm not sure how I would use this for my problem?

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
$result = $aws->DescribeInstances();
$reservations = $result['Reservations'];
foreach ($reservations as $reservation) {
$instances = $reservation['Instances'];
foreach ($instances as $instance) {
$instanceName = '';
foreach ($instance['Tags'] as $tag) {
if ($tag['Key'] == 'Name') {
$instanceName = $tag['Value'];
}
}
echo 'Instance Name: ' . $instanceName . PHP_EOL;
echo '<br>';
echo '---> State: ' . $instance['State']['Name'] . PHP_EOL;
echo '<br>';
echo '---> Instance ID: ' . $instance['InstanceId'] . PHP_EOL;
echo '<br>';
echo '---> Image ID: ' . $instance['ImageId'] . PHP_EOL;
echo '<br>';
echo '---> Private Dns Name: ' . $instance['PrivateDnsName'] . PHP_EOL;
echo '<br>';
echo '---> Instance Type: ' . $instance['InstanceType'] . PHP_EOL;
echo '<br>';
echo '---> Security Group: ' . $instance['SecurityGroups'][0]['GroupName'] . PHP_EOL;
echo '<br>';
echo '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------';
echo '<br>';
echo '<br>';
}
}
```

Comment: See, you can set the tag for the instance you are going to create and then use PHP function sleep(200), in my case, it took around 200 seconds to setup completely and then call describe instances without passing any arguments in that like $aws->DescribeInstances(). Then, simply compare the tag of the instances and and get the ID of target instance.

Comment: @IrfanAhmed :- I have try your code but not working for me. can you please me